# jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, function (err, decoded) is not decoding properly

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, jwt

My middle tear code is not giving expected output

```
const verifyJWT = (req, res, next) => {
  // console.log('jwt');
  const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
  if (!authHeader) {
    return res.status(401).send({ message: "Unauthotized access!" });
  }
  const token = authHeader.split(" ")[1];
  console.log(token)
  jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, function (err, decoded) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(403).send({ message: "Forbidden access!" });
    }
    // console.log(decoded);
    req.decoded = decoded;
    // console.log(req.decoded.email, "decod");
    next();
    console.log('decoded',req.decoded);
  });
};
```

Below lines of code gives the token properly
const token = authHeader.split(" ")[1];
console.log(token)

But Decoding is not working properly. It's provide error and not decoding. It

```
jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, function (err, decoded) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(403).send({ message: "Forbidden access!" });
    }
    // console.log(decoded);
    req.decoded = decoded;
    // console.log(req.decoded.email, "decod");
    next();
    console.log('decoded',req.decoded);
  });

 console.log('decoded',req.decoded); gives output decoded { email: '[object Object]', iat: 1655887103, exp: 1655890703 }
```

Comment: What library using for jwt ? and what is the unexpected result ?

Comment: what error exactly does jwt.verify give you? You don't even log `err`.

Comment: For the frontend I am using react and for backend I am using express node mongo. My decode with return an email but it is not returning exact email. It just return decoded { email: '[object Object]', iat: 1655887103, exp: 1655890703 }.

Comment: console.log(err) returns noting. 
In the frontend i am getting this error https://prnt.sc/qEmfWvkUgPI5
I am trying to verify the email by this code in the backend https://prnt.sc/CFEATWCEVuTp
I am requesting from the frontend by this way. https://prnt.sc/ecJiUo_ntlUw

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign string to the email. Debug the method that creates jwt token. Here is my method:

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'
const generateJwtToken = (email:string): string => {
    const token = jwt.sign({ email: email }, jwtKey)
    return token
}
```

Comment: Are you asking for this https://prnt.sc/yHYplkBNgShc

Comment: Yes but it seems to be correct. Just console.log(req.params.email). Also you can debug your jwt token here: https://jwt.io/ . It will show how your token looks as decoded

Comment: In this section of code I am getting my email address properly. But when I am try to decode my email by jwt token it relies decoded { email: '[object Object]', iat: 1655887103, exp: 1655890703 }. Where I am expecting email: '[object Object]' my email in the place of object Object.

Comment: do you have this middlewares added:
`const app = express()
app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())`

Comment: Also debug you token in https://jwt.io/

Comment: Here is my middlewares https://prnt.sc/z0EVrCcZ7Ucn

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(()=>{
        const email = user?.user?.email;
        const currentUser = {email:email};
        console.log(currentUser,'hfghfh')
        if(email){

            fetch(`http://localhost:5000/user/${currentUser.email}`,{
                method: 'PUT',
                headers: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json'
                },
                body:JSON.stringify(currentUser)
            })
            .then(res=>res.json())
            .then(data=>{
                console.log(data);
                const accessToken = data.token;
                localStorage.setItem('accessToken',accessToken);
                setToken(accessToken);
            })
        }
    },[user])
```

In my frontend code I made a mistake. I am passing and object thorough email and didn't extract the email value. Insepect of passing currentUser.email fetch(`http://localhost:5000/user/${currentUser.email}` I was passing just currentUser.

Thanks everyone for helping me for this problem.